# textContent not reading all the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I  have an xml file on the disk that contains:

```
<canvasTracking>
      <!-- GoStats JavaScript Based Code -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gostats.com/js/counter.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">_gos='monster.gostats.com';_goa=458628;
      _got=5;_goi=1;_gol='Install live web stats on your site.';_GoStatsRun();</script>
      <noscript><a target="_blank" title="Install live web stats on your site." 
      href="http://gostats.com"><img alt="Install live web stats on your site." 
      src="http://monster.gostats.com/bin/count/a_458628/t_5/i_1/counter.png" 
      style="border-width:0" /></a></noscript>
      <!-- End GoStats JavaScript Based Code -->
</canvasTracking>
```

I read the file with:

```
$.post('loadSave.php', {saveName : xml_name},       
            function(xml) {  // loaded  data is in xml
                            canvas$ = $('#canvas');
                            if ($(xml).find("canvasTracking").length) {
                                canvasTracking  =  $(xml).find("canvasTracking")[0].textContent
                            }
                            else {
                                canvasTracking = '';
                            }
```

Looking at "xml" after the read I can see that all of the canvasTracking text came down, but after the

```
canvasTracking  =  $(xml).find("canvasTracking")[0].textContent
```

line, canvasTracking contains only:

```
_gos='monster.gostats.com';_goa=458628;
_got=5;_goi=1;_gol='Install live web stats on your site.';_GoStatsRun();
<a target="_blank" title="Install live web stats on your site." 
href="http://gostats.com"><img alt="Install live web stats on your site." 
src="http://monster.gostats.com/bin/count/a_474698/t_5/i_1/counter.png" 
style="border-width:0" /></a>
```

Does anyone see the problem and know how I can get all the text?

Thanks

Comment: The correct way to embed XML as text in an XML document is by using CDATA.

Comment: I read in W3Schools "The term CDATA is used about text data that should not be parsed by the XML parser."  But in this case no is parsing it but me, with [0].textContent. It seems like I need something different to read it.

Comment: When you do `$(xml)` you are parsing it. You need to tell the parser _not_ to do that by using CDATA.

Comment: Is requirement to retrieve `textContent` , or entire `xml` document , including tag elements ?

Comment: I just want the text that is between the tags, everything between <canvasTracking> and </canvasTracking>.

Comment: Tried: <canvasTracking><![CDATA[
<!-- GoStats JavaScript Based Code -->
           - etc 
<!-- End GoStats JavaScript Based Code -->]]</canvasTracking>

but the beginning and end still get cut.

Comment: Got it!  Reading canvasTracking with  canvasTracking  =  $(xml).find("canvasTracking").html(); brings it all back. The textContent just read the text node, which excluded anything that looked like HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var canvasTracking;
$.post('loadSave.php', {saveName : xml_name}
, function(xml) {
    if (xml.firstChild.nodeName === "canvastracking") {
      canvasTracking = $(xml.firstChild);
    } else {
      canvasTracking = ""
    }
    console.log(canvasTracking)
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/mm6yc1vh/

Comment: Got it! Reading canvasTracking with canvasTracking = $(xml).find("canvasTracking").html(); brings it all back. The textContent just read the text node, which excluded anything that looked like HTML.